# Why are the Kadmonites singled out?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashat-lech-lecha

With my limited understanding of dikduk I don't know what the significance of the `־` symbol is. Maybe it  indicates that two word should be read together? I know grammatically it turns an `אֵ֖ת` to an `אֶת`. With that introduction, I'm curious about an inconsistency I noticed.

When Hashem promised Avraham a land for his descendants, He says ([Bereishis 15:19-21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#19))

> אֶת־הַקֵּינִי֙ וְאֶת־הַקְּנִזִּ֔י **וְאֵ֖ת הַקַּדְמֹנִֽי׃**
>
> the Kenites, the Kenizzites, the Kadmonites,
>
> וְאֶת־הַחִתִּ֥י וְאֶת־הַפְּרִזִּ֖י וְאֶת־הָרְפָאִֽים׃
>
> the Hittites, the Perizzites, the Rephaim,
>
> וְאֶת־הָֽאֱמֹרִי֙ וְאֶת־הַֽכְּנַעֲנִ֔י וְאֶת־הַגִּרְגָּשִׁ֖י וְאֶת־הַיְבוּסִֽי׃ (ס)
>
> the Amorites, the Canaanites, the Girgashites, and the Jebusites.”

Only the Kadmonites are lacking a `־` symbol (thus making it `וְאֵ֖ת`). Are there any meforshim that explain why they were singled out?

Comment: It's almost certainly just based on the length of the word.

Comment: @DoubleAA what do you mean by length. קדמני and רפאים seem to be the same.

Comment: No, רפאים is only two syllables (or 2.5 if you count the Shva Na). גרגשי is indeed also a full three, but it's not on a Sof Pasuk.

Comment: The 'hyphen' is called a Makkaf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation#Hyphen_and_maqaf It basically means that for the purposes of singing, treat these words as one.

Comment: It's the same for Betuel who doesn't have such a long name.  @DoubleAA

Comment: @Heshy That's after an etnachta so there's no where else for the tipcha to go.